# Reading Data From STDIN in Kernel Space

Tags: kernel, freebsd, system-calls

I'm trying to write a kernel Module for `FreeBSD 9.3.0`, and I want to use the `read` Syscall in it. I have included the appropriate headers (among others):

```
#include<sys/sysproto.h>
#include<sys/unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/uio.h>
#include<sys/cdefs.h>
```

But when I run make I get the following error:

> > implicit declaration of function `read`

I have also looked through the source files of the said headers, and searched a lot of the source tree in `sys/sys` and `sys/kern` looking for the said function, but I couldn't find it.
**Note**: I can successfully use the `printf` systemcall from the same Program.(compiled without the `read` calls)

**Update:** The Documentation actually states to include `unistd.h`. But that's in the C standard Library, and I can't use it in the kernel.So the Question becomes this, what other alternatives do I have? (I'm trying to read from `STDIN`)

Comment: You are trying to do something very strange. What's the purpose of calling `read` in the kernel? Do you do that on behalf of user? Is the data going to be placed into userland buffer?

Comment: Yes, the data will be headed to userland.(it's an assignment)

Comment: If what you want to do is read data from the user's tty device before it gets to the user's applications, it may be easier to write a line discipline.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @qarma that it's a little odd to be performing a read, in kernel space, on behalf of a user process - the user space should be issuing its own read calls, especially since all of the security checks and process policy checks are out the window when you're running in kernel mode, as well as process accounting, statistics, etc. Kernel mode requires the utmost care when dealing with data and access.

There are much better ways of getting data in and out of the kernel module. [This post on the FreeBSD forums](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/how-to-access-a-file-in-freebsd-kernel-space.45979/) mentions one:

> If you want to see how dealing with files in drivers is done properly,
>   take a look at how pf(4) uses a user space helper program pfctl(8) to
>   read the configuration file(s) and translate them into binary data
>   structures that are then fed to the kernel driver through the /dev/pf
>   device.

Alternatively, you could use user-mode programs to load data from disk/etc into a buffer somewhere and perform an ioctl to get the data in; reading and writing to a /dev/MyDriver endpoint is probably better, however.

If you truly find yourself needing to do exactly what you've asked, then that same post indicates that at least some part of the kernel writes to the filesystem - the process coredumper - the post points to `kern/kern_sig.c` as an example:

```
static int
coredump(struct thread *td)
{
    struct proc *p = td->td_proc;
    struct ucred *cred = td->td_ucred;
    struct vnode *vp;
    struct flock lf;
    struct vattr vattr;
    int error, error1, locked;
    struct mount *mp;
    char *name;         /* name of corefile */
    off_t limit;
    int compress;

...
    error = corefile_open(p->p_comm, cred->cr_uid, p->p_pid, td, compress, &vp, &name);
```

`coredump` calls `corefile_open` to open the file, taking as output `vp` and `vname`, where `vp` is a pointer to a vnode object.

Digging into `corefile_open`, we see:

```
static int
corefile_open(const char *comm, uid_t uid, pid_t pid, struct thread *td,
    int compress, struct vnode **vpp, char **namep)
{
    struct nameidata nd;
    struct sbuf sb;
    const char *format;
    char *hostname, *name;
    int indexpos, i, error, cmode, flags, oflags;

...

    flags = O_CREAT | FWRITE | O_NOFOLLOW;
    NDINIT(&nd, LOOKUP, NOFOLLOW, UIO_SYSSPACE, name, td);
    error = vn_open_cred(&nd, &flags, cmode, oflags, td->td_ucred, NULL);
...
    NDFREE(&nd, NDF_ONLY_PNBUF);
    *vpp = nd.ni_vp;
```

Note the call to `vn_open_cred` - after it completes, we can use the freshly initialized `nd.ni_vp` variable to obtain our vnode pointer. Note the calls to NDINIT and NDFREE.

If you want, you can dig down some more - `vfs_cnops.c` contains the implementation for `vn_open_cred` and might look familiar:

```
int
vn_open_cred(struct nameidata *ndp, int *flagp, int cmode, u_int vn_open_flags,
    struct ucred *cred, struct file *fp)
{
    struct vnode *vp;
    struct mount *mp;
    struct thread *td = ndp->ni_cnd.cn_thread;
    struct vattr vat;
    struct vattr *vap = &vat;
    int fmode, error;

... lots of setup ...

    error = vn_open_vnode(vp, fmode, cred, td, fp);
```

And there you have it - vn_open_vnode is finally where the real work is done.

Your best bet is probably to go through `vn_open_cred`.